# access opened html div in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

i call ajax request in A.html and when response is ok I want to show message in B.html.
(I want to show message in a div with id='mes_div' that contains in B.html )
how can I access B.html and
how should I access this div?

- I use django as server side.

Comment: [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:
Django view:
default case: -> template A.html
if condition == Load_A_Done -> template B.html

On A.html's AJAX, after loading success you call the Django View, with a form parameter like load=OK
On Django view, check if load parameter is presenting, if no, use the A.html as template, else use the B.html as template
Before using B.html, use messages

```
from django.contrib import messages

def viewAB(request):
    if request.GET.get("load") == "OK":
        messages.info(request, 'A loaded successfully')
        return render(request, 'B.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'A.html')
```

on the B.html

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
        {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}Important: {% endif %}
        {{ message }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```